# Accessing @IBOutlet from another class

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I am currently making a route-tracking app to teach my self swift. I had the basic functionality working with the route being tracked and a polylines being drawn all from within a single SessionController class, But i wanted to split the class up into separate objects.

This is where i came into problems. I put all the code that updates the location and draws polyines, etc into its own class called MapView.swift and left the @IBOutlets for the buttons, mapView, etc. In the SessionController.swift but now I can’t access the @IBOutlet for the mapView to allow the new MapView.swift class to update the current location, update polylines, etc.

When I try to ctrl+drag the mapView @IBOutlet to the MapView.swift ViewController nothing happens.

So, what I am asking is how do I link the two classes to allow access for the mapView within the SessionController to get updated with the current location.

I have being looking up on protocols and delegates but I'm not too sure how to implement them, or even if that's the correct way to go.

The code for the SessionController can be seen below:

```
class SessionController: UIViewController 
{

    // Creates an outlet link to the corrosponding interfaces on the storyBoard
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!

    var mapScreen: MapView! = nil

    // Had to change from viewOnLoad so that the custom alert class could be utilised.
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = startButton.frame.size.height/2
        stopButton.layer.cornerRadius = stopButton.frame.size.height/2

        mapScreen = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mapScreen") as! MapView)

        // does the initial check whether the location services are enabled
        mapScreen.checkLocationServices()
    }

    // ends the current session, resets buttons, stops updating location and changes to history tab.
    func endSession() {
        stopButton.isHidden = true
        startButton.isHidden = false
        mapScreen.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    // action for when the start button is presssed.
    @IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        mapScreen!.startUpdatingLocation()
        startButton.isHidden = true
        stopButton.isHidden = false
    }

    // action for when the stop button is pressed.
    @IBAction func stopButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        presentAlertWithTitle(title: "End Session?", message: "Do you wish to end your session?", options: "Cancel", "Yes") { (option) in
            switch(option) {
            case 0:
                break
            case 1:
                self.endSession()
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the MapView can be seen below:

```
    class MapView: UIViewController 
    {

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []
        let regionInMeters: Double = 500
        var mapView: MKMapView!

        //  Checks the users location services are enabled otherwise give them an alert.
        func checkLocationServices() {
            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                setupLocationManager()
                checkLocationAuthorisation()
            } else {
                // show an alert instructing on how to enable location services.
                presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Location Services Disabled", message: "Please enable your location services by navigating to Settings/Privacy/Location Services and turning on.", options: "OK") { _ in }
            }
        }

        // Setup the location manager
        func setupLocationManager() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        }

        // Checks whether the user has authorised location tracking via permissions.
        func checkLocationAuthorisation() {
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                centerViewOnUserLocation()
            case .denied:
                // show alert detailing that the user has denied access to the location services.
                presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Access Denied", message: "Request of access has been denied to the location services", options: "OK") { _ in }
            case .notDetermined:
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            case .restricted:
                // show an alert instructing that the location services are restricted i.e. child account
                presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Access Restricted", message: "Access has been restricted to the location services", options: "OK") { _ in }
                break
            case .authorizedAlways:
                break
            }
        }

        // Centers the position onto the at the specified height by using the regionInMeters variable
        func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
            if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
                mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            }
        }

        func updatePolyLine() {
            if (myLocations.count > 1){
                // get my old location
                let sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
                // get the new location
                let destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 2

                // get the coordinates for both the old and the new locations
                let sourceIndexCoordinate = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
                let destinationIndexCoordinate = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate

                // put these coordinates in to a new array so that we can get a reference to a pointer so that the MKPolyline can make use of it's position in the registry.
                var sourcePlusDestination = [sourceIndexCoordinate, destinationIndexCoordinate]

                // pass the reference of the array pointer into the constructor of MKPolyline so that a line can be drawn between the two points.
                let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &sourcePlusDestination, count: sourcePlusDestination.count)

                // adds and then updates the polyline on the map.
                mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
            }
        }

        func startUpdatingLocation()
        {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        func stopUpdatingLocation()
        {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1

            for overlay in mapView.overlays {
                mapView.removeOverlay(overlay)
            }
        }
    }

// an extension for SessionController that uses delegates to listen for changes in the location and authorisation
extension MapView: CLLocationManagerDelegate 
{

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) 
    {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: center, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        myLocations.append(locations[0] as CLLocation)
        updatePolyLine()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) 
    {
        checkLocationAuthorisation()
    }
}

extension MapView: MKMapViewDelegate 
{

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer 
    {
        if overlay is MKPolyline 
        {
            let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 4
            return polylineRenderer
        }
        return MKPolygonRenderer()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Your protocol/delegate idea seems reasonable except: Why does your `MapView` class need to be a `UIViewController`?

Comment: Honestly I’m not too sure! What would a recommendation be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your code & question, but hopefully, this can guide you down the correct path...

You create your mapScreen here:

```
mapScreen = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mapScreen") as! MapView)
```

but never set it's `mapView` property like so:

```
mapScreen = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mapScreen") as! MapView)
mapScreen.mapView = mapView
```

It also looks like you want to set the delegate of your `MKMapView` to the mapScreen as well, considering you have implemented it (`extension MapView: MKMapViewDelegate`)

e.g.

```
mapScreen = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mapScreen") as! MapView)
mapScreen.mapView = mapView
mapView.delegate = mapScreen
```

Also, I think you need a weak reference to the `MKMapView` inside `MapView`.

I also can't see how you are presenting `mapScreen`, you seem to instantiate it but not actually present it. I think a screenshot of your storyboard or some more of your code may help.

Comment: While this stops any exceptions being thrown, it don’t update the location. The initial center on the users position works but the doesn’t update when there’s movement

Comment: @Stimo Added something on my answer. I can't see where your `mapScreen` is presented